# Unit Test Dropbox

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create a unit test with Karma Jasmine that interacts with the Dropbox api.

Below is the test. It compiles the directive, then runs a click on it. This checks that the file picker window opens. Checking the window opening in this way works on other tests, but in this instance it fails because `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Dropbox` . This is because its not in the test. The file is hosted directly with Dropbox via https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js, so i cannot seem to inject it... So the question is, how do i make `Dropbox` available in this case?

```
it(": clicking button should open Dropbox Picker window", function(){

    var element = $compile("<span data-dropbox extensions=\"extensions\"></span>")($scope);

    $scope.$digest();

    var theButton = element.find('button');

    spyOn($window, 'open');

    theButton.triggerHandler('click');

    expect($window.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong. You are trying to unit test a button click. You do not unit test a button click, you unit test controller / service/ directive code.

To test a button click you use protractor. This is an E2E test (end-to-end).

Comment: Will using protractor solve the issue of getting the Dropbox code into the test?

Comment: protractor is used to test button clicks and the front end. A protractor test might be, when I click this button then I expect there to be ten items in the HTML ul list. Now if those ten items are retrieved from dropbox then you know dropbox is working. That's why its called an E2E test. It tests the whole system end to end. In respect of your dropbox code I have no idea where that is located for unit test purposes since it has not been provided. If it is located in controller code then yes you will need to unit test it but not via a button click. Instead by calling the controller function.

Comment: I see, so i will need to select items from the drop box also. Think this will lead to more issues as you need to login etc to use the api

Comment: i would suggest creating a custom dropbox service for all dropbox requests, similar to how angular provides an $http service for all HTTP requests. However, since I haven't got a great working knowledge of coding with dropbox I suggest you are better placed to make that decision.

Comment: In respect of logging in, you need to create spies to mock responses from the login API during your test. This is an important part of testing any fully functional SPA / web app from a unit test perspective. Not sure how that works in the protractor world. In respect of testing dropbox you do not need to do that beyond making sure you are sharing the right files. You just test your code and your hookup with it. Dropbox test dropbox :)

Comment: This is an existing code base, but i might be able to get the time to rewrite it... Im not 100% it will make a lot of sense making this a service, but i think it could be done